# l-rectangle component does not update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, vue-component

I am using the l-rectangle in a Vue leaflet project.
I am creating a rectangle like so:

```
<l-rectangle :bounds="rectangle"></l-rectangle>
```

which displays the rectangle on my map doing this in the .js-file:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            rectangle: [[69.81310023846743, 16.929931640625004],[69.11310023846743, 16.129931640625004]]
               }
    }
});
```

I have created a map click event, in this function I am changing the coordinates of the rectangle array in order to make the rectangle change size/shape. But nothing is happening (the function gets called but the rectangle does not change):

```
clickEvent:function(event)
{
        var point = [event.latlng.lat,event.latlng.lng];
        this.rectangle[0] = this.rectangle[0];
        this.rectangle[1] = point;
}
```

Thanks for any help and guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Vue documentation, the reactivity for array will not work if you set value for a particular index, Instead you can use some array operation methods which are mentioned in [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods)

**push()
pop()
shift()
unshift()
splice()
sort()
reverse()**

*the following above methods makes the array reactive*

> The click event can be replaced with

```
clickEvent:function(event)
{
        var point = [event.latlng.lat,event.latlng.lng];
        this.rectangle.splice(0, 1, this.rectangle[0]);
        this.rectangle.splice(1, 1, point);
}
```